# What is the minimum and maximum number of jet bridges used on an Airbus A380?

Tags: airport, ground-operations, airbus-a380

What is the minimum and maximum number of jet bridges used for embarking and disembarking on a typical Airbus A380 trip and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
([Airbus](http://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html))

The typical is two, one for each level. Three is [not uncommon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/17392/14897). Any more and the jet bridges will encroach on the adjacent gates, reducing the number of available parking spots at terminal. The right side is busy with other servicing equipment.

Also note the aft-left area being used for catering.

[image]
([gulfbusiness.com](http://gulfbusiness.com/dubai-airports-boost-a380-stands-dxbs-concourse-c/))

---

- [Why do passenger embark on the left side of an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9096/14897)
- [Why aren't planes loaded from both ends?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12309/14897)
- [How long does it take to refuel a big jumbo jet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26132/14897)
- [Airbus patent for detachable cabin](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9193460) (patents.google.com)

Comment: Its not impossible though to design a system, airport or modify an airport that can use all 14 exits as embarkment and disembarkment points at the same time without disrupting and encroaching on the adjacent gates, and not at all reducing the number of available parking spots at terminal, even allowing all the other equipment on the right side to funtion symultaniously?  Is that correct?

Comment: Some of the exit are only exit (the one over the wings). For the other, like you can see on the schematic, they are used for catering, it will be difficult to add more fingers to get people in. And the Emirates configuration with 3 jet bridges is plenty enough. After that technically, you can use all the doors to get people in and out, except the emergency exit.