# Are all the Airbus A380's 16 exits designed for everyday use?

Tags: airbus-a380, doors

Are all the Airbus A380's 16 exits designed or everyday use for embarking and disembarking the aircraft, or are some specifically designed for use as emergency exits, such that opening any of those designated as emergency exits would require specialists to put them back in place?

In other words do all have hinges for everyday use?

Comment: Related: [What is the minimum and maximum number of jet bridges used on an Airbus A380?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50056/14897) / The answer shows how an A380 is typically serviced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the 16 exits are hatches. All 16 have identical operation. From the A380 FCOM:

> The aircraft has 16 passenger doors (...) The doors open forward. The opening/locking of the door is performed mechanically by moving the door handle. In normal operation, the door revolves electrically by pressing the OPEN pb, or the CLOSE pb. In emergency operation, the door revolves automatically. In the case of an electrical power loss, the door can be manually operated. There is a flight lock actuator in each door that locks the door handle during the climb and descent phases, in order to prevent inadvertent operation during flight.

[image]